# Cython code getting slower on each new call

Tags: python, arrays, multiprocessing, cython, shared-memory

I have a set of processes that asynchronously update two arrays located in shared memory w/o locking. They use the following cython code:

```
@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
@cython.nonecheck(False)
cdef void c_apply_grads_rmsprop(float[::1] m, float[::1] g, float[::1] p, 
                           unsigned int p_size, int _type, 
                           float lr, float alpha, float e) nogil:

    cdef unsigned int i
    for i in range(p_size):
        m[i] = alpha * m[i] + (1 - alpha) * (g[i] ** 2)
        p[i] -= lr * g[i] / sqrt(m[i] + e)

def apply_grads_mom_rmsprop(m, g, v, v_size, _type, lr, alpha, e):
    c_apply_grads_mom_rmsprop(m, g, v, v_size, _type, lr, alpha, e)
```

Both `m`, `p` and `g` are passed to the cython function as numpy arrays. `g` is a "pure" numpy array that is populated with new data before every call. `m` and `p` point to arrays located in shared memory. They are created as `RawArray(ctypes.c_float, size)` and wrapped into numpy arrays with `np.frombuffer(..., ctypes.c_float)`.

If I only have one process, the function's average execution time seems to be stable. However, when I launch several processes, the average execution time continuously increases. Why is this happening?

On a side note... Could my code be further optimized?

Comment: I guess with several processes there will be collisions, when two or more processes try to write to the shared memory at the same time, but that should not increase the execution time. Or am I wrong?

Comment: I don't know about the parallel problem, but you can add the compiler directive ```@cython.cdivision(True)``` to make your function faster.

Comment: It's a float division, it's not affected by ``cdivision``.

Comment: `cdivision(True)` tells cython not to check for `ZeroDivisionError` which saves a little time with float division. Looking at your code, I don't see where you benefit from using cython, have you timed ur code compared to vectorized numpy implementation?

Comment: What platform, what multiprocessing model, what other stuff is the program doing, etc.